# How to update a record on termination (spring boot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm inserting records to a table in batches and on termination I would to update a records status(a column) to failed. How can I do this? I'm doing this in spring boot.

Comment: By termination you mean termination of application? Like stopping the application?

Comment: Yes! @narendra-choudhary.. is that possible?

Comment: You can put database calls in `@PreDestroy` method in any `Bean` which closes before database connection manager bean.